# Sum of Kloosterman sums with oscillating factor

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums, trace-formula

Denote by $S(c;n,m)$ Kloosterman's sum.  Take $X>0$ and take $n,m\in \mathbb Z$ smaller than a small power of $X$ in modulus.  It is known that essentially
\[ \sum _{c\sim X}\frac {S(c;n,m)}{c}\ll X^{1/6}\hspace {10mm}(1),\]
see Theorem 1 of "Ganguly, Sengupta 2012 - Sums of Kloosterman sums over arithmetic progressions".  I would like to know what can be said for the sum
\[ \sum _{c\sim X}\frac {S(c;n,m)}{c^{1+it}}\hspace {10mm}(2)\]
for $t$ something like $\sqrt X$ (or some other small-ish power of $X$).

My main question is "What can I expect in this case?  Can I expect a similar bound to hold?".

Here are some (quite useless) thoughts: If I use partial summation I lose a factor $t$, so I don't want to do that.  And if I try to look at the proof of (1) in the above paper:  First they replace the unweighted sum in (1) by a weighted sum - this is Proposition 8 and the proof surely goes through when we replace $c$ by $c^{1+it}$, leaving us to estimate
\[ \sum _{c\sim X}\frac {S(c;n,m)\phi (4\pi \sqrt {nm}/c)}{c^{1+it}}=\frac {1}{(4\pi \sqrt {nm})^{it}}\sum _{c\sim X}\frac {S(c;n,m)\phi (4\pi \sqrt {nm}/c)}{c}\left (\frac {4\pi \sqrt {nm}}{c}\right )^{it}\]
for $\phi $ a smooth weight, which they then tackle using Theorem 7 - see the top of Page 163.  I could then look at $x^{it}\phi (x)$ as a new test function but now the derivatives are larger than the original one by factors $t/x$, which will probably be a problem.

Any pointers would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Does $c\sim X$ mean something like $X<c<2X$?

Comment: yep, exactly that